# Bind listboxitem content to dependency property of the listbox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, listboxitem, checkedlistbox

I'm trying to make a custom control checkedlistbox in WPF with custom Checkedlistbox item

Xaml code for checkedlistboxitem:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CheckedListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CheckedListBoxItem}">
                <CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=Content}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Xaml Code for checkedlistbox :

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CheckedListBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBox}}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:CheckedListBoxItem Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Checked Listbox class :

```
 public class CheckedListBox : ListBox
{
    static CheckedListBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CheckedListBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CheckedListBox)));
    }



    public string ItemBindingName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ItemBindingNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemBindingNameProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemBindingName.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemBindingNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemBindingName", typeof(string), typeof(CheckedListBoxItem), new PropertyMetadata(""));


}
```

Checked listboxitem class:

```
public class CheckedListBoxItem : ListBoxItem
{
    static CheckedListBoxItem()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CheckedListBoxItem), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CheckedListBoxItem)));
    }



}
```

and iam using it in a window with the following xaml code:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource GroupBoxStyle}"  Header="Choose Categories :" >
        <local:CheckedListBox ItemsSource="{Binding AllCategories}" ItemBindingName="{Binding Name}"  />

    </GroupBox>
```

What I want is the following :

To make that customcheckedlistbox so generic such that I don't have to enter the name of the property which I am binding to in the template itself (i.e. I want to remove Content="{Binding Name}" part from template ), instead I created a dependency property called "ItemBindingName" for the checkedlistbox & I want the item template to bind the property which its name is in the "ItemBindingName" property (i.e. when I write ItemBindingName="{Binding xxx}" in the declaration of checkedlistbox, the template binds to the "xxx" property automatically)

Sorry if my question sounds not understandable enough,
I really tried hard to simplify it, this is the best that I can get.

Comment: Why don't you just put a CheckBox in the ItemTemplate of a regular ListBox? There doesn't seem to be any need for a derived ListBox and ListBoxItem. There isn't even a binding of the CheckBox's IsChecked property in the CheckedListBoxItem template.

Comment: @Clemens i will add IsChecked property later along with alot of other specific functionality that i need alot (jumping to specific selection with keyboard and binding checked items with observabole collections...etc.) but for the time being and as a part of its generic behavior i need to define the property that iam binding to outside the template (in the listbox declaration)

Answer (score 0):

Your CheckedListBox class should override the following methods. In `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` it would establish the Content Binding.

```
protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    return new CheckedListBoxItem();
}

protected override bool IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(object item)
{
    return item is CheckedListBoxItem
        || base.IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride(item);
}

protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(
    DependencyObject element, object item)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ItemBindingName))
    {
        ((ContentControl)element).SetBinding(
            ContentControl.ContentProperty, new Binding(ItemBindingName));
    }
}
```

---

As a note, the Content Binding in the ControlTemplate of the CheckedListBoxItem could just look like this:

```
<CheckBox Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ... />
```